# Двойной массив и вывод его

Tags: php

Пытаюсь сделать цикл со счетчиком. Необходимо сделать график кол-ва банов по времени unix, решил делать так:

```
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_sb)) {
    $data[] = date('d', $result['created']);
}

for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    if($data[$i] == NULL) {break;}
        $cnm = $i -1;

        if($data[$i] == $data[$cnm]) {
            $cntbans[$i][$b++];
        } else {
            $b = 1;
            $cntbans[] = $data[$i];
            }
}
 print_r($cntbans['14']);
```

Но как мне вывести второй массив "кол-во банов" из $cntbans['День']['кол-во банов']

P.S. Дни уже записаны в виде 16,16,16,16,17,17,18,18,19,19...

Answer (score 0):

Правду говорят: быстрее самому решить, чем объяснить кому-то)))
оставлю код, вдруг пригодится кому-то

```
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_sb)) {
    $data[] = date('d', $result['created']);
}

for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    $cnm = $i -1;

    if($data[$i] == $data[$cnm]) { 
        $b++;
    } else {
        echo $b. " ";
        echo $data[$cnm];
        echo "<br>";
        $b = 1;
    }
    if($data[$i] == NULL) {break;}
}
```